# Knockout: Handle events on foreach elements

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
<div id="resultlist" data-bind="foreach: content">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="result" data-bind="event:{ mouseover:myfunction, mouseout:myFunction2}">

                <div class ="resultlisticoncontainer">
                    <div class="resultcontenttypeIcon myclassHidden" data-bind="css: { myclassVisible: newClass() == true, myclassHidden: newClass() == false }">
                        <object id="contentIcon" data="img/File_Icon_24x24.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
                    </div>

                    <div class="resultcontenttypeIcon myclassHidden" data-bind="css: { myclassVisible: newClass() == true, myclassHidden: newClass() == false }>
                        <object id="marple" data="img/Glass_Icon_24x24.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <p><span data-bind="text: name" class="filenamestlye"></span></p>
                <p><span data-bind="text: file_path" class="urlstyle"></span></p>
                <p><span data-bind="html: highlight" ></span></p>
            </div>      
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what i want to do is, when i put the mouse over the div with class "result", the divs with class "resultcontenttypeIcon" should get visible. This works fine, but the problem is, that this happens to every div child that is created with the foreach loop. So what i want is, that only the div childs of the hovered div become visible, so that the event mouseover is not triggered for every div. I think the problem is, that the newClass value becomes true for the whole viewmodel.

This is my viewmodel code:

```
function ItemListViewModel() {

    newClass= ko.observable(true);
    myfunction = function() {
        newClass(true);

    },
    myFunction2= function(){
        newClass(false);         
    },
}
ko.applyBindings(new ItemListViewModel());
```

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS :hover classes to hide/show the result instead? It would be simpler and faster.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I gave the "result" div the :hover .resultcontenttypeIcon {display: block; } style and the resultcontenttypeIcon  the style display:none;. So if i hover over "result", the child div is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find CSS is easier to make this happen. Here is a JSFiddle that does what I think you want. I've replaced the objects with images to make it work on screen. Obviously layout is broken as we don't have your CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/010vn1ra/

The method is quite simple: the class to be hidden is defined as `display: none` by default.

We then add a `:hover` on the `result` class that changes the `display` of the child class. This means you don't need any bindings to do this.

Comment: Thank you, too. Did already change it to the css style version. Works perfactly.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `:hover` selectors indeed work well if you have no dependencies that change with which element is hovered over. But if for example you want to display a text with the index of the element in the list somewhere else, change a template or trigger a function, you still need to bind the event.

We can prevent the element to which the event was bound to 'absorb' the event thanks to the parameters Knockout passes to bound functions: `data` & `event`.
With a little target checking, your container mouseover function looks like this:

```
app.updateHovered = function(data,e) {
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
   // ko.contextFor passes the context of the object, including the $index observable
       index = ko.contextFor(target).$index(); 
   // the following check depends on your elements of course
   if (target.nodeName === 'DIV' && target.parentNode.nodeName === 'DIV') 
      app.isVisible(index); // isVisible holds the currently 'selected index'
}; // and a simple 'false' setter on mouse out
app.removeHovered = function(data, e) { 
   app.isVisible(false); 
}
```

Example HTML for the above:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list, event: { mouseover: updateHovered, mouseleave: removeHovered }">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: $index, visible: $index() === $parent.isVisible()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<h3 data-bind="text: typeof isVisible() === 'number' ? 'Howdy, you selected item ' +  isVisible() : ''"></h3>
```

See the very simple **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s86ged03/)** in which the `isVisible` property holds the $index of the last hovered list-item.

In fact, this is about delegating events, so you might also want to check out R. Niemeyer's [Knockout-delegatedEvents](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-delegatedEvents) binding, which automates this process for you.